# Geodesics in $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I am trying to solve an Exercise in the book   *Audrey Terras - Harmonic Analysis on Symmetric Spaces and Applications I-Springer (1985)* and I struggle to find good justifications.

In the exercise, we consider the hyperbolic plane (model is the upper half plane $(x,y), y > 0$, with metric $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}/y^2$) and $C(z,w)$ is a geodesic path (meaning a half circle or straight line perpendicular to the "x-axis") joining $z,w \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty \}$. $\overline{C}(z,w)$ is the projection into $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of said path and *closed* is defined (in the exercise) through the existence of a parametrization (say $\overline{c}$ in $X:= \mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ of $\overline{C}(z,w)$ such that $\overline{c}(t)$ has the same begining and end points.

The first question of the problem has two parts, I must show that:

1. $\overline{C(z,w)}$ is closed $\iff$ there is $\gamma \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\gamma C(z,w) \subset C(z,w)$.
2. $\overline{C(z,w)}$ is closed $\iff$ $z,w$ are fixed points of a hyperbolic element of $\gamma$ of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

When discussing the Problem, I was told that it is an issue if we go through vertices of a Fundamental domain, or some Fix Point of an element of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but I don't get it and I haven't found good references to get a better understanding of this specific issue, so that would be welcome.

The main analogy I work with is that of Lattices (in $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, euclidian). Geodesics are any lines ($y= ax+b$) and projecting them into a fundamental domain (a square with opposite sides identified / a torus) accordingly, but this doesn't seem to reflect this ambiguity...

Here goes what was my attempt at a proof of one implication:

1. $"\implies"$: $C(z,w)$ is infinitely long, but it's projection has finite length. Therefore, if we call $[\cdot]$ the projection into a fundamental domain, at any point $y \in C(z,w)$, we can find $d \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that for an arc length path $c : [0,d]$ in $C(z,w)$ starting at $y$, the map
   \begin{align*}
      \overline{c_y} : [0,d] &\rightarrow  X, \\
                      t &\mapsto [c(s+t)]
   \end{align*}
   isn't injective and we can choose $d$ to be minimal. For $L$ such a minimum, it follows that $[c_y]$ is $L$-periodic in $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ for any starting point. Therefore, $[c_y(0)] = [c_y(L)]$  and $c_y(0) \neq c_y(L)$. By definition, this means that there exists $\gamma \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $c_y(0) = \gamma c_y(L)$ for all $y \in C(z,w) \implies \gamma C(z,w) \subset C(z,w)$.

P.S. I may write down my attemps for all of 1. and 2. at some point

Here is the Problem (Ex. 20, p277) as found in the book (don't mind the highlights) :

[image]

Comment: Claim 1 is false, you have to assume that $\gamma$ is hyperbolic.

Comment: Your definition of "closed path" is wrong. The definition of "closed path" that you wrote is for a path parameterized by a closed interval like $[0,1]$ or $[a,b]$, which is not the situation you are in.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike You confused me. The claim is about the existence of an element in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\overline{C}(z,w)$ is closed. Hyperbolic elements are a subset of that. So that doesn't falsify the claim.

Comment: What I wrote is correct, you do not get $\iff$ statement unless you exclude elliptic elements. In the extreme case, take $\gamma=\pm I$. Then $\gamma C=C$ for each $C$ but $C$ need not project to a closed geodesic.

Comment: @LeeMosher The definition given in the Book (which can be seen in the Picture), "closed" is defined through the fact that "once correctly parametrized, the beginning of the curve is the same point as the end of the curve". Doesn't that imply that there is such a closed Interval?

Comment: Lee Mosher is also right, your definition of a [closed geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_geodesic) is simply wrong. If this is how your instructor or textbook defines closed geodesics, look for alternatives to either one.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I get your point. But this implies that I wrongly stated the question in the exercise. Yet, I don't see where I mistransalted...

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I am solving an exercise of a book using the definition of "closed" given in the statement of said exercise. I hope that my new edit clarifies that.

Comment: With the wrong definition given by your book, you will never solve the problem. What book is it? My suggestion is to change the textbook. There are many decent books on hyperbolic surfaces.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I mention mention the book in the first two lines of my post. However, you can find a PDF [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGWCGdIGDWwTA6Y6-rNGzwEgg6O8G-Gd/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: I see, I did not notice. Then supplement (or replace) with Helgason's book on symmetric spaces and harmonic analysis. It is astounding how many basic mistakes Terras's book is making just in one page.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am quoting the Book (which is explicitely mentionned in my Post) and the image in my Post contains all of this information. Any helpful reference is welcome. I am wholeheartedly trying my best.

Comment: What mathematical topic do you want a reference for? $\text{SL}_2 \mathbb Z$  is certainly a special and very important example of a lattice acting on the hyperbolic plane. Are lattices what you want to study? If so, this example is not the best starting point, because of the presence of elliptic elements (which this author handles very poorly).

Comment: @LeeMosher A reference (or anything) that would help me understand geodesics in $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. For example, the role of hyperbolic elements and the length of these geodesics.

Comment: My general context is that I am trying to grasp the relationship between these geodesics and class numbers.

Comment: Yeah, okay, that's a good case for really wanting to understand $\mathbb H / \text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$. Unfortunately I can't help you regarding references for the connections to class numbers (John Tate once explained it to me, but that doesn't help you). I suggest you write a sharp and focussed question on that topic (and perhaps references for it), with your interests clearly described.

Comment: For some information connecting $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ to class numbers, see [this question on math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236151/conjugacy-classes-of-mathrmsl-2-mathbbz/236162#236162), my answer to that question, and the comments under my answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher But do you have any reference regarding Geodesics in $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ ? 
(The Exercises 18-20 in this book by Audrey Terras actually are exactly about that connection, and I understand (well, I think) the Number Theoretic part. However, the geodesic part is what I am missing.

Comment: @LeeMosher I actually stumbled upon this Post a few months ago, when I was just starting to look into the topic. Since I am writing a text for myself about exactly that (with references to the relevant papers) I could share it with you once I'm done if you are interested, (for the small chance that it is of any use).

Comment: Again, geodesics in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ are kind of a speciality topic, and  I don't have a good reference in mind for you, but a sharp, focussed question regarding references might elicit good suggestions.

Comment: Try a google search on the key words *geodesics on the modular surface*. On that list, about 10 or 15 items down, I see [a paper by Caroline Series](http://reu.dimacs.rutgers.edu/~ks1613/documents/series.pdf) which looks very good.

Comment: There is also [this paper by A. Pohl and D. Zagier](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.01067) (which is what started my quest, and they reference Terras Book, which is how I stumbled upon it).